# how to reference a file of higher hierarchy in a java servlet project

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

i'm trying to implement a basic mvc pattern for a java web app project in netbeans. i have the deployment descriptor (web.xml) correct but i can't seem to redirect to the correct jsp from the java servlet itself. here's the directory of my project folder:

```
/project
  /src
    /conf
      MANIFEST.MF
    /java
      /ph
        /com
          /client
            /esurvey
              /objects
                /* other .java files */
              /servlets
                ManageSurveysServlet.java
                /* other .java files */
  /build
    /empty
    /web
     index.jsp
     manage_surveys.jsp
     script.js
     style.css
     /META-INF
       context.xml
       MANIFEST.MF
     /WEB-INF
       web.xml
       /classes
         .netbeans_update_resources
         .netbeans_automatic_build
         /ph
           /com
             /client
               /esurvey
                 /objects
                   /* .class files found here */
                 /servlets
                   ManageSurveysServlet.class
                   /* other .class files found here */
```

a link from `index.jsp` calls the `ManageSurveysServlet` which in turn forwards a `request` object and redirects to `manage_surveys.jsp`, but given the above directories, i don't know what path/filename to use to reference `manage_surveys.jsp` with from the servlet. here's the code in the servlet that forwards the request object:

```
request.setAttribute("surveys", surveys); // surveys is an arraylist
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("manage_surveys.jsp"); // i'm guessing it can't find the jsp
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

UPDATE: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ManageSurveysServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ph.com.client.esurvey.servlets.ManageSurveysServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ManageSurveysServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/ManageSurveys</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config>
  <welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but does `"/" + request.getContextRoot() + "/manage_surveys.jsp"` work?

Comment: i'm afraid the HttpServletRequest object `request` doesn't have the method getContextRoot()

Comment: my mistake, it's `getContextPath()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `manage_surveys.jsp` into `WEB-INF` folder.I think that will be solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc says the given resource is a relative path. So executed in the classes dir means, you have to either put your jsp in the "classes" dir, but thats not a good idea, but for testing reasons u may try or 
change your code to context root relative:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/manage_surveys.jsp");
```

or relative:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("../../manage_surveys.jsp");
```

The Javadoc for reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)